# Assembly language: Ampersand before a register

Tags: assembly, beaglebone-black

I'm trying to program the Programmable Realtime Units (PRU) on my Beaglebone Black in assembly language. [Here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Instructions) is the instruction set, which comes in two flavors: `pasm` and `clpru` (I'm using `pasm`).

What does it mean when a register name has an ampersand (&) before it? [For example](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Instructions#Store_Byte_Burst_.28SBBO.29):

```
// Copy 8 bytes from r2/r3 to the memory address r1+5
sbbo &r2, r1, 5, 8
```

How is this different than just

```
sbbo r2, r1, 5, 8
```

?

Comment: This seems to be a programming, not an EE question, and would fit much better on StackOverflow, IMHO.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Questions which are specific to embedded programming are fine here. See [this discussion](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/are-pure-c-questions-on-topic).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev ah, thanks. Clearly, this is one of these questions on the boundary between the SO and the ee.SE communities :) I still think this is less about embedded than understanding the assembler language on its own, but I can certainly see why it's asked here. That's why I commented, but did not flag (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

From the instruction set provided in the link it is evident that

```
sbbo &r2, r1, 5, 8
```

is the only supported in `clpru` assembler. But in `pasm`

```
sbbo r2, r1, 5, 8
```

is also supported. So, in `pasm` they are same. But if `clpru` was used only the first syntax would work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it does just what the comment says. With the & it copies the content of the register (plus the next one up since 8 bytes are specified). Without the & it copies data from memory at the address specified by the value in the register.